# PHP SoapClient: Get list of all functions with parameters

Tags: php, soap, parameters, wsdl, soap-client

I am consuming a SOAP web service from a third party vendor, and we are having some issues with the functions in the service changing randomly (renamed parameters, parameters added and removed). Obviously this isn't what we want to see happening, so I am trying to write a script to notify me whenever anything in the Webservice changes.

Using PHP's SoapClient, I can pull a list of all functions in the webservice, however all of the functions list a single parameter which appears to be the container for the rest of the parameters. I am using the SoapClient in WSDL mode, so I would think that there is some way to pull a full parameter list for each function.

Any advice?

Comment: when you say pull a full parameter list do you want this behind the scenes or do you want to look at it?  the wsdl should show you all of that.

Comment: That vendor should offer versioned API so that it's clear which is still supported and how the next one looks like. As that's obviously not the case, you can only fingerprint the WSDL I think.

Comment: @Robert - I want to create an automated way of documenting what functions exist and what parameters they require at a given moment. If I need to manually parse the WSDL to do that I will, but I was hoping there might be an easier way.

Comment: @hakre - Do you have any advice on how to go about accomplishing this by saving a more human friendly listing than a straight WSDL?

Comment: I don't know of anyway to get parameters without using the wsdl and if they update their code they should be providing you with the updates especially if it's breaking existing functionality.  This sounds like a process issue more than a development issue.  So to answer your question yes you will need to parse the wsdl but shouldn't have to the vendor should tell you things are changing and give you ample time to adjust your system to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of what some of the comments above had said, if you are not able to get accurate reflection of the methods/parameters to meet your needs from the SOAP client, then certainly there is nothing to stop you from either taking a hash of the WSDL itself and comparing it to a hash you have stored to see if there are any changes.

If you wanted to get more detail on what the changes are, then you could go a step further and parse the WSDL with some XML library and compare nodes for changes.